# Golang import package from root directory

Tags: go, goland

I'm trying to create a clean architecture API in Go but I'm confused with package logic. Here's the structure of the project.

```
    main.go                <- package main
    ├── delivery/
    │   ├── endpoints/
    │   │   ├── users.go   <- package endpoints (I want to import ./repository here)
    │   │   └── home.go    <- package endpoints
    │   ├── router.go      <- package delivery
    │   ├── middleware.go  <- package delivery
    ├── repository/
    │   ├── database.go    <- package repository
    │   └── fetchUsers.go  <- package repository
```

In `router.go` file I can access and import endpoints like this `import "./endpoints"`, but when I try to import repository package inside `users.go` or inside `home.go` I get an error. Is there a way to access repository from files that are in endpoints folder?

Comment: Do not use *relative* imports!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only recommended/canonical way to do imports is with full paths. If your code lives in `github.com/Uranus/myproject`, then in `endpoints/users.go` you should import `repository` thus:

```
import "github.com/Uranus/myproject/repository"
```

Note that it doesn't actually have to be on github. Using modules, you can have any import path you like while developing locally, as long as it's the module name in your `go.mod` file.

Follow the examples from [this official Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) and you'll know what to do.